# Running .exe with a .manifest file causes a "...did not install correctly" dialog. Why?

Tags: windows-7, manifest, pca

I'm trying to get a VB app (*my.exe*) to run as Administrator on Windows 7. So I'm using a Manifest (below) to do that. But when I run it (and immediately exit the My.exe) I get the Program Compatibility Assistant warning:
"This program might not have installed correctly"
Of course, I am not doing any installing.

- If I set the EXE to *Run As Administrator*  (by right-clicking My.exe ) then I do **not** get this warning (with or without the manifest present)
  or
- If I remove the manifest file (and set exe to run as admin or do not do that) I do **not** get the warning.

Any ideas why this is happening and how to NOT get this warning using the Manifest?

MANIFEST

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<assembly xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" manifestVersion="1.0">
  <!-- Make My Manifest 0.7.300 -->
  <assemblyIdentity name="Bungalow.Software,.Inc..CDCodes" processorArchitecture="X86" type="win32" version="10.0.0.16" />
  <description>Internal BSW program to generation installation and actvation codes</description>
  <trustInfo xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
    <security>
        <requestedPrivileges>
          <**requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false"** />
        </requestedPrivileges>
    </security>
  </trustInfo>
</assembly>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a [compatibility section](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd371711%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) in your manifest.

Answer (score 0):

Your manifest says "I am an admin app; I change this computer" but when it has finished running, the registry is unchanged, program files is unchanged, etc. So Windows wonders to itself -is everything ok? And then it asks you.